# Linking in MathOverflow account with the others?

Tags: discussion, linked-accounts, mathoverflow

I have my SO, Meta and Area 51 accounts 'linked', but not my MathOverflow, even though I used the same OpenID account for all of them?  Why isn't MathOverflow also 'part of the family' ?

Comment: Probably because they don't own that.

Answer (score 4):

MathOverflow is a Stack Exchange 1.0 site, which is not technically linked to The Stack Overflow Trilogy, nor Stack Exchange 2.0.

Comment: So I have to ask MO to 'upgrade'?

Comment: @Jacques That will be an option for MO, but it looks like from their meta discussion (at meta.mo) that they will not be moving to 2.0 because there are fairly major changes to the administration of sites.

Comment: The current status is that MO is optimistic that we'll be able to migrate, but it depends on negotiations with the the SE people which hasn't fully happened yet.

Comment: There is a [Mathematics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics) proposal which has reached the commitment phase in Area51, btw.

Comment: @eagle clearly the site should be called mathunderflow.com.